# how to hide table when its empty - Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row

Tags: jquery, jsf, datatables

I am getting this warning

**DataTables warning (table id = 'userList'): Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 0**

**I know I am getting this warning** ***because table is empty. I don't have data in table.***

I want to know, how can I ignore this warning and show the empty table? I meant  with just headers.

What I have is as below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#userList').dataTable( {
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bSort": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sType": "natural" },
            null
        ],
        "oLanguage": {
            "sEmptyTable": '',
            "sInfoEmpty": ''
        },
        "sEmptyTable": "Loading data from server"

    });
});
```

&

```
<h:dataTable id="userList" value="#{FullScopeBens.gtAllDealsForMe()}" 
             var="userInfo" bgcolor="#{msg['tableColor']}" border="1" cellpadding="5" 
             cellspacing="1" width="100%" style="color: #{msg['fontColor']}; border: 1px solid white;"
             columnClasses="setNWCol01,setNWCol02"
             >
    <!--                                <f:facet name="header" class="centerText">
                                        <h:outputText value="News" style="font-size: 18px;text-align: center;color: #{msg['backColor']};"/>
                                    </f:facet>-->

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <br />
            <h:outputText value="Sr. No." />
            <br />
            <br />
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="#{userInfo.serNo}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

---

### Edit 1

Thiis is what  I get in HTML

```
<table id="userList" bgcolor="#F1F1F1" border="8" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" dir="LTR" width="100%" class="dataTable">
<thead>
<tr><th colspan="4" scope="colgroup"><span style="font-size: 18px;text-align: center;">Countries</span></th></tr>
<tr>
<th scope="col" class="ui-state-default">Serial No.</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
<tr><td class=" "></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

In java I have below.

```
public List<NewsBean> fetAllCompData() {
    try {
        db = new ConnectToDatabase();
        conn = db.makeconnection();

        PreparedStatement psmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC");
        ResultSet rs = psmt.executeQuery();

        List<NewsBean> myList = new ArrayList<NewsBean>();
        long testNum = 1;
        while (rs.next()) {
            NewsBean newsBean = new NewsBean();
            newsBean.setId(rs.getString(1));
            newsBean.setSrNo(testNum + "");
            newsBean.setNewsEn(rs.getString(2));
            newsBean.setNewsAr(rs.getString(3));
            newsBean.setWhenAdd(rs.getString(4));
            testNum++;
            myList.add(newsBean);
        }

        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }

        return myList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception while fetching data " + e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now when I don't have data in news table I will not get anything.

When I print myList I have nothing inside it...

```
System.out.println("myList in news===" + myList);

myList in news===[]
```

Comment: Pls provide your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Damn! Why didn't I do this at first?

Just search for `function _fnLog( oSettings, iLevel, sMesg )`

Hide the below statement:

```
var sAlert = (oSettings===null) ?
"DataTables warning: "+sMesg :
"DataTables warning (table id = '"+oSettings.sTableId+"'): "+sMesg;
```

Now you will not get an alert.

Comment: If all else fails... delete! ahahaa... Man (1), Machine (0)

Answer (score 1):

How empty is your table ?

`datatable` will still need to have the header row, with the expected number of columns.

The error message seems to suggest there is at least one row with one cell in your table. Double check the generated html.

Also, check what your `FullScopeBens.gtAllDealsForMe()` function returns when there is no data in your mysql table.

Comment: In your html : the `tobdy` contains `<tr><td class=" "></td></tr>`. To represent an empty table, it should contain no row. Look for the reason why you have this invalid row in your table.

Comment: when I return, I get output as `myList in news===[]`

Comment: damn... I found solution... I downloaded newer version where this is taken  care..